# Ionic 4 time doestnot exist on type {}

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need in help my code i am not able to find solution here is my code.

```
getAllMessages(){

  this.messageService.getAllMessages().pipe(map(messages => messages.sort((a, b) => b.time.seconds - a.time.seconds)
   )).subscribe((data)=>{
     this.data = data;
       console.log(this.data);
      });    
}
```

I need to rearrage array by time like the newest time array will on top and lowest on last. And its working by this code but problem is its showing the error

```
error TS2339: Property 'time' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Any one please tell how can i solve this thanks :)
[image]

Comment: `b['time']['seconds']  - a['time']['.seconds']` , it would  be great if you could add the `messages` sample data  to the question so that we can see what data it has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the error, you need to pass the type, change the code as

```
messages.sort((a : any, b : any) =>
```